# Groovy not compiling properly in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I'm trying to write my first groovy class.  When I do so, Eclipse complains about syntax errors as though it's parsing a Java file.  It wants semicolons on the end of each line, it doesn't recognize the "def" keyword, etc.

I have both Groovy 1.7.5 and the latest Groovy Eclipse plugin installed.  I have also converted the project to a Groovy project and opened the file in the Groovy editor.

What else could be causing this:

[image]

---

EDIT:
update - even when I disable all builders via *project properties > builders*, I still get the red lines.  What causes this?  I thought the builders were responsible for creating the lines and markers???  If I can figure out "who" determines errors/problems in an open workspace file, I could deactivate that functionality...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AspectJ/Groovy combination is not working inside of Eclipse.  They each require their own builder and they are not compatible with each other.  The only way that this will work is if you separate your AspectJ and your Groovy code into different projects.

This combination may work in Maven since it can use different compilers for different source folders.  However, there may be a circularity problem your aspect code depends on your groovy code (which in turn depends on your aspect code).

Comment: arg!  That's frustrating but it makes sense. Recently, I created a custom builder (that accomplishes everything through ant). I'd love to disable the Groovy builder and rely on our builder, alone but I don't see a groovy builder in the project's Builders list. Puzzlingly, when I disable all builders, I still get the red lines... even after closing/reopening the project... this doesn't make any sense.  Who is responsible for those red lines, if not a builder?!

Comment: Right.  There is no groovy builder since Groovy-Eclipse ships with a patch for the Java Builder so that it can compile both groovy and Java code.

The red squiggles in the editor does not come from the builder, but rather from the reconciler.  After every editor change, the reconciler is called, which performs an operation that is kind of like compilation, but only for the current file and no class files are produced.  This is how you can get very detailed problem reporting in your Java and Groovy files even if you haven't saved them.

Comment: thanks. "Reconciler" should be very "google-able." So far, I've found [this helpful blog on Reconcilers](http://blog.darevay.com/2007/11/the-eclipse-reconciler/trackback/). Overall, the Groovy-Eclipse extension seems like it's very poorly coded; as if the developers didn't take time to follow the Eclipse architecture. I'd like to just turn the Groovy Editor's reconciler off, completely!  Sheesh.

Comment: How is this an answer? Nothing you have said helps the poster find a solution.

Comment: @Jon: in my edit I asked *I still get the red lines. What causes this?  I thought the builders were responsible* and he directly answered this in his second comment. I see your new answer below and, the next time I'm in eclipse, I'll check if it works for me also...

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this before.
My usual response to resolve this is to:

1. Close / reopen the project.
2. Confirm the project is converted to a groovy project
3. Clean and rebuild the project.

If that doesn't work...You can try to create a new project with the existing source.

good luck!

Comment: Tried the steps above.  It didn't work.  This sucks. lol.  When I right click the file and run it, it works.  I created a new groovy project, cut/paste the same code into the same file name under the same package, and it works perfectly without errors. My other project is maven/aspectj/groovy... I wonder if that combination confuses the editor, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I found that updating to the latest snapshot build fixed my compile issues.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1003

Put this into your install new software...:
http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.6/

Comment: Next time I'm in eclipse, I'll add that update site and see if the snapshot works for me. At a conference, I talked to one of the guys who wrote groovy and he didn't seem to interested in making the eclipse plugin work with AspectJ.  So to "solve" the problem I had to move my groovy code into it's own project, which was less then ideal. Hopefully, this will allow me to move it back...

Comment: The problem here is that the 2.1.1 release is not compatible with Eclipse 3.6.2.  However, 2.1.2 is now available from the update site and you will no longer see this problem.

Comment: @gmale It's not that we're not interested in making the AspectJ compiler and Groovy compiler work together, it's just that it is a very, very difficult problem.  We would need to make significant changes to both compilers for this to work.  And considering that AspectJ works reasonably well weaving into Groovy byte code (but just not source code), we have less of an incentive to work on this.  Of course, it would be very cool to write your aspects using Groovy syntax, we just have many other more pressing issues to work on with both languages.

Comment: @Andrew: yeah, that's the same general gist I got from the brief conversation I had with the Groovy guy. It's completely understandable.  I was less concerned with doing awesome groovy aspects (although that sounds *very* cool) than I was with just having my groovy code "live," in the same AspectJ-enabled project without the errors pictured above. Of course, it was *NOT* hard to move my groovy stuff to a separate project to sidestep the problem. Still, I'm glad to hear you guys addressed *that* particular issue and we can move our scripts back over! Great news. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, the incompatibility with 3.6.2 is what was causing @Jon Stevens problem.  It is still not possible to combine your groovy scripts with your aspect project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same problem. I also get an error when I try to create a new Groovy script or class. I get an error dialog saying:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit cannot be cast to
org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyCompilationUnit
```

I've tried moving the Groovy source files to a different folder that is not set as a Java source folder, and the syntax error highlighting problem goes away, now. I still have to avoid doing "New > Groovy Class", though. I just create a plain file and name it with a ".groovy" extension, and it seems to be OK with that.

Clearly there are significant issues with this plugin.

Comment: My apologies for posting this as an answer rather than comment. Newbie mistake (plus I don't have privileges, yet, to comment). I should add that I updated to the latest version of the plugin and this seems to working OK, now.